# Roboguice is not injecting dependencies

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm using Roboguice to inject my dependencies but it's not workink. I have a class that extends RoboActivity and my attribute still null.

```
public class SplashActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject
    private PropertyReader propertyReader;

    @Inject
    Vibrator v1;

}
```

Should i do some aditional config?

Thank in advance.

Edit: it only works if i do **RoboGuice.injectMembers** in every class that i have  objects to injects. Can i do it only one time for the whole app?

Comment: How is the activity created? Where do you access this variables (in which functions)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the injected non view fields after the activity onCreate. InjectMembers runs in super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) you dont have to call it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   v1.vibrate();
}
```

view fields should be used after onCreateView() is called.